# Push Data from UserForm to specific cell on a designated worksheet using comboboxes to select the target cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops, combobox, userform

Longwinded title but hopefully an easy fix, so thanks for stopping by.

I have a Userform with comboboxes (For Different Employees, Months and Days) and a Textbox (Hours holiday used)
The form contains 10 Comboboxes for month and day to allow for multiple entries (this is all relevant to the question I promise).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxwoa.jpg)
I would like to send the data input in the Textboxes to a cell dictated by the 3 Combobox selections. The target Sheets are all same layout (1 per employee) Column headers are Months and rows are days (numbered)

I've got a code from an old project which performed something similar, I thought with a couple of tweaks it would work, I know theres errors in there but if theres some pointers to get it working that would be fantastic, i've listed comment to best describe my intentions, also i'm not sure LastRow isn't the best option but didn't know an alternative (I thought Range?):

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ComboDay As String
    Dim ComboMonth As String
    Dim I As Integer

'Open up sheet for data entry

    'Dim WBK As Workbook

        'Set WBK = Workbooks.Open(".xlsm")

    'Windows(".xlsm").Activate


    Dim ws As Worksheet
      If ws.Name = UserForm1.ComboBox1.Text Then
     End If

            LastRow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row       'LastRow for the loop


'Identifying date and time
ComboDay = UserForm1.ComboBox2.Text            'day number from Combobox
ComboMonth = UserForm1.ComboBox3.Text           'Month selected in the ComboBox

For I = 1 To LastRow
    If (ws.Range("C" & I).Text = ComboDay) And (ws.Range("D" & I).Text = ComboMonth) Then  'I know D range in ComboMonth is wrong - this is part of the old code which looked in two columns for date and time- how can this be changed to look across the columns (which are in row 16 on the sheet currently)
        ws.Range("ComboDay", "ComboMonth" & I).Value = TextBox1.Text 'this is my basic attempt to illustrate how i want the code to look for the cell which is defined by the comboboxes
        ws.Range("G" & I).Value = TextBox2.Text ' these below are all the old code - combo boxes on the form are all odd numbers from 3-21 for month and day are even from 2-20
        ws.Range("I" & I).Value = TextBox3.Text
        ws.Range("K" & I).Value = TextBox4.Text
        ws.Range("M" & I).Value = TextBox5.Text
        ws.Range("O" & I).Value = TextBox6.Text
        ws.Range("Q" & I).Value = TextBox7.Text
        ws.Range("S" & I).Value = TextBox8.Text
        ws.Range("U" & I).Value = TextBox9.Text
        ws.Range("Z" & I).Value = TextBox10.Text
    End If
Next I

Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```